# Execute a SOAP based web services dynamically without generating proxy

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

In my application, end user can fetch the data from any SOAP based web services and use it in the application. The application provides an option to register the service on fly. The application examine the service, show available operations along with parameter, finally execute the selected operation and use the response, of course everything will be on the fly. There are few steps need to be follow in order to achive that:

1. Discover the service through WSDL
2. Examine it and select a method
3. Build required parameter values
4. Execute the service
5. Handle the response

I am able to discover the service on the fly using some WCF classes like DiscoveryClientProtocol, WsdlImporter, ServiceDescription, ServiceContractGenerator, etc. Now, I want to execute them and take the response XML that is available inside SOAP Body.

I am able to execute it by generating the Assembly at runtime using above library and execute a method through reflection. This solution works fine if I have to do everything in single-shot on a box. But it adds complexity when we scale-out. That means, one server generates the proxy, another one use the proxy and consume the services.

Yes, we can keep newly generated assembly somewhere in shared location and use them. But I want to avoid them. We want to keep service definition locally somewhere in DB, execute it without generating assembly and just consume the XML available inside SOAP body.

Appreciate the advice in advance on how to achieve this?

Comment: I did try this with a console application long time back. You do not need to build an assembly to invoke a service. You can list down all the actions the service supports(which I believe you already did) and send a SOAP message the service expects. I did this with some xml helper.

Comment: @Nilesh, how do I generate the SOAP message? I would not prefer to generate the message manually as it would be difficult to cop-up with different version of SOAP, hence prefer to use WCF or any existing framework that takes care of SOAP version, security, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with WCF services without code generation you use the [ChannelFactory< T >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132(v=vs.110).aspx) where T is the service interface.

Obviously in your case the service interface is not known at compile time so your objective would be to dynamically generate this type, or better yet use a custom ChannelFactory implementation that does not rely on strong typing and lets you call methods in a dynamic or programmatic way.

You can use the [WsdlImporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter(v=vs.110).aspx) to import the WSDL at runtime and which can give you the [ContractDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.contractdescription(v=vs.110).aspx)s. From there you might be able to use [ContractType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.contractdescription.contracttype(v=vs.110).aspx) as your service interface but I'm not sure. You may need to write your own ChannelFactory...

Comment: that's exactly what the issue I have that how to write customized channel factory? And on top that I don't want any object in return, I would want XML that is raw serialized data comes from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ChannelFactory to your abstract generic BaseFactory class which has override CreateDescription method to set Binding and Endpoint for ChannelFactory.ServiceEndpoint. You can pass your configuration interface which has Binding, Endpoint and Credentials to this abstract class. So you can have a dynamic proxy for a wcf service.